# Disable access to SharePoint sites/files but user retain access to their personal OneDrive

Tags: onedrive-for-business, sharepoint-permissions

Is it possible to disable a user's access to companies SharePoint sites/files but the user should be able to access their personal OneDrive ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? Would you want to disable ALL sharepoint sites except their own OneDrive for a user, is that what you meant? And is this SharePoint Online or on-premises?